# Real Analysis, Folland Mutual singularity of positive measures Problem 3.3.8

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Relevant background information:

We say that two signed measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $(X,M)$ are mutually singular if there exists $E,F\in M$ such that $E\cap F = \emptyset$, $E\cup F = X$, $E$ is null for $\mu$ and $F$ is null for $\nu$. We express this as $\mu\perp\nu$.

Suppose that $\nu$ is a signed measure and $\mu$ is a positive measure on $(X,M)$. We say that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and write $$\nu \ll \mu$$

Problem 3.3.8:
Suppose $\{\nu_j\}$ is a sequence of positive measures. If $\nu_j\perp \mu$ for all $j$, then $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\nu_j\perp \mu$; and if $\nu_j\ll \mu$ for all $j$, then $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\nu_j\ll \mu$.

Attempted proof: Let $\{\nu_j\}$ be a sequence of positive measures, and let $\nu_j\perp \mu$ for all $j$. Then there exists a measurable set $E_j$ such that $E_j$ is $\nu_j$-null and $E_j^{c}$ is $\mu$-null. Define $E:= \cup_{1}^{\infty}E_j$ and note that $E^c = \cap_{1}^{\infty}E_j^{c}$. So, $E^c$ is $\mu$-null. Then (this is where I think it goes wrong) by contunity from below $E$ is a null set with respect to $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\nu_j$. Therefore $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\nu_j\perp \mu$.

I haven't tried the second part yet but I think it is pretty trivial (tongue and cheek moment). Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @hermes yea I noted that, I was just trying to prove the first part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first part, it should be proved as:

Since for any $j$ $\nu_j\perp \mu$, there are $E_j$ that is null for $\mu$ and $F$ that is null for $\nu$, such that $E_j\cup F= X$ and $E_j\cap F= \varnothing$. Let $E= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j$. Then
$$
E\cup F= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j\cup F\supset E_j\cup F=X
$$
So $E\cup F=X$. Also
$$
E\cap F= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_j\cap F=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}(E_j\cap F)=\varnothing
$$
So $E\cap F=\varnothing$.

Thus $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\nu_j\perp \mu$.

Comment: Nice proof, for the second part. By the same procedure you applied wouldn't it imply that $v_j \ll \mu$?

Comment: That it is absolutely continuous and mutually singular? I am not sure if I understand you question.

Comment: If you are asking for a condition I provided a definition to absolutely continuous on the question, my apologies if I am not understanding you

Comment: I see noted thank you